# pick image from gallery in one activity using button and send it to another activity

Tags: android, android-intent, bitmap, image-gallery

In my layout, I am using a button to pick the image from gallery and I want on clicking the button on the current activity of the concerned layout it should take the image from gallery and send it to the another activity where I want to dispaly it.I used imageview in the other activity layout.I am using this code,gallery is not opening so unable to fetch image..correct me plz.

Current Activity :

```
private static final int REQUEST_CODE = 1;
    private Bitmap bitmap;
    private ImageView imageView;

 public void onClickPickImage(View view){

        Intent intent = new Intent(this,GreetingCard.class);
        intent.setType("image/*");
        intent.putExtra("bmp_Image", bitmap);
        intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
        intent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_OPENABLE);
        startActivityForResult(intent, REQUEST_CODE);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        InputStream stream = null;
        if (requestCode == REQUEST_CODE && resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK)
            try {
                // recyle unused bitmaps
                if (bitmap != null) {
                    bitmap.recycle();
                }
                stream = getContentResolver().openInputStream(data.getData());
                bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(stream);

                imageView.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
            } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } finally {
                if (stream != null)
                    try {
                        stream.close();
                    } catch (IOException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
            }
    }
```

next activity :

```
ImageView imageResult = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.image_result);
        imageResult.setImageResource(getIntent().getIntExtra("bmp_Image",R.id.image_result));
```

Comment: I am unsure of what you are asking. It seems like you are simply posting your code and asking other people to fix it or write it for you. This is not what StackOverflow is for. Try clarifying what problem you are having, what you have done to try and fix it, and specific questions that you have.

Comment: gallery is not opening so unable to fetch image